# Why does hitting enter in a textbox trigger a click-event in another button

Tags: javascript, html

Consider This:

```js
  const button = document.querySelector('#button');

  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("why did this happen?");
  });
```

```html
<form>
<label for="input">L<input type="text" id="input" name="input"></label>
<button id="button">B</button>
</form>
```

Go into the textbox and hit Enter. You see an alert, which indicates that the click-event of the button got triggered. But why did this happen? I can understand, that the enter event bubbles up to the form and triggers a submit. `preventDefault` prevents this. But what does the button have to do with it?

Comment: Instead of the button try the form as the listener for the 'submit' event rather than the 'click' event. ex `document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', eventHandler)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressing Enter in a single text box in a form triggers form submission by way of simulating a click on the default submit button.

I think the historical motivation is so that when people add a click event to the submit event without considering that people might expect Enter to submit a form it still works.

Comment: I even knew that but it's quite surprising that a button-element which is not of type `submit` can be considered as standard-submit button. I hope, I can find some documentation how exactly this behavior is defined to work with it.

Comment: Found it... https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#default-button

Comment: @Paflow — It is of type `submit`, that's the default value of the `type` attribute